# How do I determine who the ISP of an IP is?

Tags: ip, isp

I'm looking for a way to find the ISP of a given IP address. How do I know what ISP assigned this IP address to a user?

**Edit:** Thanks for the information about whois lookup queries @LPChip and @AFH! That's an excellent way to find in-depth information about an ISP. I've done some more research and it turns out there are also sites that provide an easier way to find the ISP of an IP, such as [whoismyisp.org](http://www.whoismyisp.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to perform a whois lookup to get information about an ip address. There are a few major organisations who keep track of IP addresses for certain areas, such as North America, South America, Europe, Asia, etc.

There are also sites that will use all these databases and let you query globally.

One of these sites is http://who.is

Enter the IP Address in question in the search bar and you'll see which organisation is responsible for this IP address, including contact information for abuse etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you use one of the many "whois" sites, they will tell you who owns any IP you specify.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @warren - On the contrary, it answers the question precisely. The question was perfectly clear, and I do not require clarification. I did not spell the answer out in the same detail as LPChip, because I thought the questioner might learn from doing a little research on "whois".

Comment: that comment was left by the review system, and was *NOT* typed by myself.

Comment: @warren - Sorry if I was a bit abrupt: I didn't know "the review system" could make comments in one's name. I'll need to be careful of that in the future when making my own critiques. Does that mean that one-line answers are always deemed unacceptable?

Comment: *typically* ultra short answers get flagged as needing review because they *tend* to be spam/comments posing as answers. I wish I knew reviewing your answer (which, ftr, i upvoted) would leave a comment. I'd've come by and clarified/deleted the auto-generated comment had I known. I know now :)

Comment: As mentioned, this is not a helpful response without some more detail.  There are a number of whois sites that only work on domain names (e.g. [mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/Whois.aspx)) so it would be somewhat of an exercise in frustration to try and find one that works (particularly if you assume that the OP had already done a basic Google search before coming here).

Comment: @HappyDog - I wish it were true that questioners always do Google searches before posting, but sadly this is often not true. As I said in a previous comment, I thought that the questioner might benefit more by investigating "whois" sites, learning their individual facilities and strengths. Besides, any individual site that I might have recommended five years ago would not necessarily be available or have the same facilities now.

Comment: True, regarding link rot, but that applies to any question that contains a link - it's not a good reason not to include one.  Whether or not the questioner would benefit from being given half an answer doesn't change the fact that it is half an answer.

Comment: If the bare bones of an answer makes the questioner do some work from which he or she will learn, then I see that as a positive benefit. If you disagree we will need to differ in our opinions. End of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

A simple call to the `whois` command-line binary with the IP address of your choice will return many information including a field named *org-name* that contains what you refer to as the name of the ISP.

Another solution is to use a service such as [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) (disclaimer: I run the service) that returns among others, this information.